# What is a 44h command?

Tags: datasheet, hex

I am reading the datasheet of a devive and don't understand the format of the commands. They are talking about 44h and BEh commands. I assume the h just stands for hex. If so, I don't understand why they don't write 0x44 or 0xbe to make it clear.

Comment: Just matter of choice of the author.

Comment: Different strokes for different folks. You don't have to force the world into a single approach. People can choose to represent things in different ways. And they do! Just get used to it. That's all.

Comment: Because 0x44 is a C-ism and C isn't the only programming language. 44h is more universally understood outside the C software community

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I assume the h just stands for hex?

True.

> If so, I don't understand why they don't write 0x44 or 0xbe to make it clear.

the 0x prefix originates from the creators of C (just to distinguish from decimal numbers), so it's widely used in C and C-derived languages. h suffix originates from intel-derived assembly languages.

There's nothing magical.

Comment: Ah thanks. I probably would have known if I had finished that assembly tutorial by now.

Comment: @neolith you can accept my answer if it's satisfactory enough, so that the question does not remain open.

Comment: You can only do it after a few minutes ;)

Answer (score 2):

- The `h` suffix is (arguably) the most correct way to write hex numbers with no specific implementation in mind. Coincidentally it is also used in Intel-flavoured assembler.
- The `0x` prefix originates from C programming and generally means that C is somehow involved in the device.
- Other symbols exist too, such as `$` prefix in Motorola-flavoured assembler.

When writing technical documentation, you can often not assume that the reader knows C programming. They could still know hex though, maybe they are for example programming in assembler or a PLC language.